# Pass "ID" variable to JQuery Script

Tags: php, jquery

Hopefully someone will be able to answer my question.

I have a php script, inventory_edit.php, that has the GET variable ID=xxx passed to it from which it does a search to return the results.

What this loads is an edit product screen, which has JQuery enabled divs which load individual PHP scripts once the tab has been clicked. The scripts called by JQuery use a session set within inventory_edit.php, $_SESSION['Product_ID'].

The JQuery is called by inventory_edit.php with the following code.

```
<script src="js/pm/inventory_edit.js"></script>
```

The content of inventory_edit.js is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('functions/inventory_edit_stock.php', function(data) {
        $('#stock_contents').html(data);
    });
    $("#stock").click(function(){
        $("#stock_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_stock.php');
    });
    $("#pricing").click(function(){
        $("#pricing_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_pricing.php');
    });
    $("#suppliers").click(function(){
        $("#suppliers_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_suppliers.php');
    });
    $("#reordering").click(function(){
        $("#reordering_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_reordering.php');
    });
    $("#other").click(function(){
        $("#other_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_other.php');
    });
    $("#tecdoc").click(function(){
        $("#tecdoc_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_tecdoc.php');
    });
});
```

What i really need to do is pass the GET['ID'] variable to these files in some way to achieve the following WITHOUT using sessions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('functions/inventory_edit_stock.php?ID=xxx', function(data) {
        $('#stock_contents').html(data);
    });
    $("#stock").click(function(){
        $("#stock_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_stock.php?ID=xxx');
    });
    $("#pricing").click(function(){
        $("#pricing_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_pricing.php?ID=xxx');
    });
    $("#suppliers").click(function(){
        $("#suppliers_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_suppliers.php?ID=xxx');
    });
    $("#reordering").click(function(){
        $("#reordering_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_reordering.php?ID=xxx');
    });
    $("#other").click(function(){
        $("#other_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_other.php?ID=xxx');
    });
    $("#tecdoc").click(function(){
        $("#tecdoc_contents").load('functions/inventory_edit_tecdoc.php?ID=xxx');
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am new to JQuery so i am trying to get as much advice as i can.

Thanks In advance
Pete

Comment: Tried using `data` option of `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )` `$("#stock_contents").load("functions/inventory_edit_stock.php", {ID:"xxx"})` ? See http://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete

Comment: How do i set the XXX? {ID:"xxx"}, how do i pass the variable from PHP to JQUERY

Comment: _"How do i set the XXX? {ID:"xxx"},"_ At second parameter to `.load()` . _"how do i pass the variable from PHP to JQUERY "_ What is expected response from `php` to jQuery request ?

Comment: Peter...just a few quick tips. First rename your file so it ends in .php (if not already named as such). Then when you want to embed PHP variables in javascript you can do so by the following example :{ID:"<?=$myVar?>"}) basically this is PHP shorthand for echo the value of this variable. Hope this gets you going in the right direction !

Comment: Thanks Jim_M, Ive now renamed it to .php and it works a treat. Thank you people